# Dynamically Set Array Size C++

Tags: c++

I don't know any C++ at all but I am trying to make a very small update to a C++ library that my application is using. Before I start hacking away at this, I am hoping someone can tell me the proper syntax for the following:

I have the following lines of code:

```
#define A_NUMBER 100
#define ANOTHER_NUMBER 150

enum {
   type1,
   type2,
 };

static int someMethod(int type)

{
     char command[A_NUMBER];
     //...more code
}
```

What I need to be able to do is based on the type argument (type1 or type2) I need to be able to set the size of the array to be either A_NUMBER or ANOTHER_NUMBER.

In pseudo code it would be something like:

```
if (type == type1) {
    char command [A_NUMBER]
}
else if (type == type2) {
    char command [ANOTHER_NUMBER]
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically define the size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [`std::vector<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
if (type == type1) {
    std::vector<char> x(A_NUMBER);
} else if (type == type2) {
    std::vector<char> x(ANOTHER_NUMBER);
}
```

Remember to include the header with:

```
#include <vector>
```

---

> While your example code matches the "pseudo code" in the question, I think part of the question is how to decide the size via type and then use the resulting storage unconditionally, i.e. outside the conditional blocks.

Then it gets as simple as:

```
std::vector<char> x;
if (type == type1) {
    x.resize(A_NUMBER);
} else if (type == type2) {
    x.resize(ANOTHER_NUMBER);
}
```

Comment: While your example code matches the "pseudo code" in the question, I think part of the question is how to decide the size via `type` and then use the resulting storage unconditionally, i.e. outside the conditional blocks.

Comment: @delnan, can you please see if the edit match what you meant?

Comment: It does, except that you probably mean `.resize()`, not `.reserve()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want

```
std::vector<char> x; // x is empty, with size 0

if (type == type1) {
    x.resize(A_NUMBER); // change size to A_NUMBER
} else if (type == type2) {
    x.resize(ANOTHER_NUMBER); // change size to ANOTHER_NUMBER
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. In standard C++, you cannot keep the array on the stack and have its size determined in runtime.

However, you can turn the array into a dynamically-allocated one (i.e. on the heap). In C++, the standard way to do this is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> command(A_NUMBER); // or ANOTHER_NUMBER
```

Indexing will work just as before: `command[5]`

However, if you need to pass the array to something which expects a C-style array (i.e. a `char *`), you'll have to use one of these:

```
command.data();  // if your compiler supports C++11

&command[0];  // if it does not
```

And of course, to use `std::vector`, you'll have to `#include <vector>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works in C and C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *opt;
    if(argc == 2) {
        opt = *++argv;
    }
    else {
        printf("Usage: %s [small|large]\n", *argv);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int *arr;
    int arrlen = 0;
    if (strcmp(opt, "small") == 0) {
        arrlen = 3;
        arr = (int *) malloc(arrlen*sizeof(int));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < arrlen; i++)
            arr[i] = i+1; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(opt, "large") == 0) {
        arrlen = 5;
        arr = (int *) malloc(arrlen*sizeof(int));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < arrlen; i++)
            arr[i] = i+1; 
    }
    if (arrlen > 0) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; arr[i]; i++)
            printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(arr);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example:

```
[gyeh@gyeh stackoverflow]$ ./dynarr
Usage: ./dynarr [small|large]
[gyeh@gyeh stackoverflow]$ ./dynarr small
1, 2, 3, 
[gyeh@gyeh stackoverflow]$ ./dynarr large
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

Answer (score -1):

The raw C++ way is `new` and `delete`

```
char * command = new char[A_NUMBER];
// and later delete it like this
delete[] command;
```

Of course you'll have to manage the memory, and it is not recommended to use this approach because of many reasons you should be able to find online. So in conclusion... **don't use this method if vector is an option**

If using a big array the best way would be to use C++ `vector`, you could even consider other data structures like `list` based on your needs (for example a lot of insert, deletions operations on your array).

Comment: Please, sir, do not ever suggest using naked pointers. Especially to a person who is not experienced with C++.

Comment: You're not technically wrong, due to the "raw" adjective, this is still a *terrible* way and shouldn't even be discussed at length, let alone recommended.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Why not ? It's a correct answer and we are talking about c++ aren't we ?

Comment: I do see both your points... but this answers the basic question "Is there a way to dynamically define the size?" To bash on me like I did a sin is just denying knowledge... Naked pointers are still an important subject to learn

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's not correct. It *works* in the strictest technical sense, but it does not work well, is not idiomatic, it is error prone, and there are literally three better ways. We don't need to teach beginners every single footgun at once, especially in a language like C++.

Comment: @delnan It does work "well" as you point it out... It is error prone because of the handling of pointers. But it is correct, and some people like me use raw pointers when possible, and because of it we have to code more to make sure no one misuses them. Your problem is more dogmatic than a clear point of "why not to recommend this way"

Comment: It's a bad decision, bad to do, and you're bad for suggesting it. It's not correct.

Comment: @MichaelWalz We're trying to push people away from that low level, hacky, obsolete style, so of course we'll consider it incorrect for that purpose.

Comment: I don't like the "DON'T UNDERSTAND POINTERS" way programmers are taking

Comment: The goal is not simply to answer questions, but to answer them with best practices and modern approaches in mind.  If someone Google's this question and sees this answer, it will perpetuate raw pointer style, which some would go so far as to call deprecated in modern C++.

Comment: @Claudiordgz I don't like the "I don't care it works" way you're taking.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel As I said, I have to use raw pointers, and we test for it. Depends on the application, if I am programming for RTOS I rather use my raw pointers. It depends on the application, not on "it works." The are a lot of ways to get to rome. But I wont shut my eyes blind to all that I must learn beforehand.

Comment: @Claudiordgz Where do I point out that it works "well"? Anyway, raw pointers are all-around inferior and harder to use correctly. That is why it should not be recommended. We don't go around recommending people eschew cars and transport their goods via horse carts, because hey, it works, right?

Comment: The problem is not that we don't understand pointers. We do. The problem is that you appear to be in total denial about how incredibly worthless they are as an alternative to std::vector.

Comment: @delnan Would you please point me to some papers clearing out how raw pointers are inferior for Low Level C++ Programming?

Comment: I've never... Ever... Not one time, said they were a better alternative to a vector... NOT ONE TIME, you are the ones biased, you are the ones pointing things that are just not there, and instead of putting the APPLICATIONS you should use one above the other you decide to say "Don't look here, ever"

Comment: I never said you said they were better. I said that you don't understand that they're *totally worthless*. If you *can* use a vector to solve a problem, you always would. The only use cases for pointers are the cases `vector` cannot solve, and this is not one of them.

Comment: @Claudiordgz Are you silently introducing additional assumptions via the words "Low Level" or are you dense? People already mentioned several downsides several times over. To repeat, to use raw pointers here means to write more code (this you even mentioned yourself!) and risk tricky errors that could easily be prevented. There are uses for raw pointers even in the most modern shiny C++11 code; but *this* is not a good use case for them even in gritty legacy-ridden C++98 code.

Comment: I think is great that people recommend vectors, a few years ago this was not the case. But I do believe it is better to say "Don't use this method, but this is what vector does underneath, it is unsafe, hard to maintain, and requires more structure" than to say "gtfo gtfo gtfo"... damn it people I'm not a cockroach

Comment: I have much less of an issue with the answer in its current shape (and removed my downvote accordingly). Nothing fundamentally wrong with discussing other techniques. I would give the topic less exposure in my answer, but it's your typing. It's presenting raw pointers as the sole/best alternative that's outright harmful.

Comment: @delnan, I do agree with you, I just feel the need to tell people "if you play with fire you will get burnt"